# Optional compare in query

Tags: entity-framework

Hi i have a problem with my query because i want select that items which brands are called in string subcategory. But if that subcategory is equal "none" i would to select them all i want to do it in query not in linq. Here's my function

```
string subcategory = HttpContext.Current.Session["subcategory"].ToString() == "none" ? "" : HttpContext.Current.Session["subcategory"].ToString();
        List<int> processors = (from x in context.Processors
                                      where (x.Price >= filters.PriceMin && x.Price <= filters.PriceMax)
                                      where x.Brand == subcategory
                                      select x.Product_ID).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not SQL.  You should tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for this in LINQ and EF is to build up the query differently for the two cases before the query is executed by calling IQueryable.ToList();  eg:

```
string subcategory = ...;
var q = from x in context.Processors
        where (x.Price >= filters.PriceMin && x.Price <= filters.PriceMax)
        select x;

if (subcategory != "none")
{
  q=q.Where(x => x.Brand == subcategory);
}

var processors = q.Select(x => x.Product_ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks and one more question what is a different between this query and return context.processors.ToList() ?

Comment: This query has filters that will be translated to SQL and evaluated by the database server.